# How do I rig Firebug 1.2 to behave the way previous versions did?

Tags: firebug

After waffling for months I've installed Firefox 3 on my development machine and am regretting it, because the new Firebug is sucking my will to live.  Flakiness aside--it's not catching basic syntax errors--there's a whole new layer of UI all over everything, and it's making me THINK.

Please, can somebody tell me the series of choices I need to make to get Firebug to behave exactly the way it did--just show everything all the time, please, and quit bugging me to re-POST to get results in my Net tab--before I upgraded?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using 1.2.0a21X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress ... smart co-worker pointed me at about:config for part of the answer.  I toggled extensions.firebug.allowDoublePost to true, restarted Firefox, and the Net tab quit asking me to re-POST.